# Bootstrap fixed side bar and header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make sidebar fixed in bootstrap along with navbar and header.

I have the following structure:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>

<body>

        <div class="page-header custom-header">
                <center>
                        <h1>Example Page Header</h1>
                </center>
        </div>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                                        ....
                        </div>

                        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                                <li>...</li>
                                                <li>...</li>
                                                <li>...</li>
                                        </ul>

                                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                                                <li>...</li>
                                                <li>...</li>
                                                <li>...</li>
                                                <li>...</li>
                                        </ul>
                         </div>
                </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="wrapper" class="toggled">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <!-- Sidebar -->
                                <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                                                <li>...</li>
                                                <li>...</li>
                                                <li>...</li>
                                                <li>...</li>
                                    </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->


                    <br/><br/><br/>


                    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                        <div class="container">


                                <div class="row">

                                    <div class="col-xs-6"  style="background-color:lavender;">...</div>

                                    <div class="col-xs-7" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">...</div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color:lavender;">...</div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The sidebar and navbar can be made fixed, while with header I face problems. If navbar is fixed, header is scrolled down with the content. I tried adding

```
top: 0;
position: fixed;
```

But it only resulted in sidebar overlapping the header.

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fyzyc54k/). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good start by changing the following CSS:

```
.page-header {
    padding: 20px 0 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
}


#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

It will still take some adjusting to the different viewports, start with the mobile then style up.

https://jsfiddle.net/fyzyc54k/4/

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a genius! Html is very hard to me and it's amazing how people like you can do it minutes! Thanks!